# how to disable gallery view scrolling

Tags: android

hi 
i want to disable gallery view scrolling when we select particular item in gallery view.\
how do i do that. kindly help me out.

Answer (score 2):

Write your own gallery class that extends Gallery. Override the onFling method with something like this :

```
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY){
if (itemIsSelected)
    return true;
else return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
}
```

set the the itemIsSelected flag in your onItemClickListener.

Hope that helps.