# Android Custom gallery to disable scrolling

Tags: java, android

I'm attempting to create a custom Gallery to disable scrolling. I've got the following from this: [how to disable gallery view scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865488/how-to-disable-gallery-view-scrolling)

```
 public class MyGallery extends Gallery{


public MyGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY){
    if (isSelected())
        return true;
    else return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
    }

}
```

Doesn't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Note the `if (isSelected())` clause in example, you might want to omit that and return `true` unconditionally, completely avoiding inherited implementation.

Overriding `onFling` prevents flings but doesn't affect regular scrolling, with finger down. To do that, try also overriding `onScroll` and immediately returning true from there.

If that doesn't work either, you can also override `onTouchEvent` and filter touch events there.

Answer (score 0):

I have use CustomListview in Linearlayout. and disable scrolling using below code

```
public void enableDisableView(View view, boolean enabled) {
        view.setEnabled(enabled);

        if ( view instanceof ViewGroup ) {
            ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)view;

            for ( int idx = 0 ; idx < group.getChildCount() ; idx++ ) {
                enableDisableView(group.getChildAt(idx), enabled);
            }
        }
    }
```