# Disable gallery scroll view on Android

Tags: android, gallery

I use Gallery to show photos.
And it can scroll to previous or next one by touch screen.
But I want to set a button to lock the gallery.
I use below code to implement it:

```
gallery.setEnabled(false);
```

But it still can scroll view by touch screen.
How can I arrive it?

Comment: you need to create the custom gallery see the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409402/android-custom-gallery-to-disable-scrolling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

override the `onTouchListner` for your gallery

```
gallery.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

     return true;
  }
 });
```

Comment: It's the best solution of this issue!