# Android - How do I lock (freeze) a gallery component?

Tags: android, locking, scroll, gallery, block

I have a gallery and a listview right below it.

As the user goes through the gallery, new items are downloaded from the Internet and added to the listview. The thing is: I don't want to allow the user to scroll the gallery to the next item while its listview has not yet loaded. I know that that is not what the user want but the component that I'm forced to use here (a SOAP one) only left me with that option.

Pay attention that the UI will only be partially blocked, that is, only the gallery component will be blocked for as long as the Internet request last. The listview will never be blocked.

So, **how do I block the movement of a gallery**?

Thank you in advance! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this post: [how to disable gallery view scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865488/how-to-disable-gallery-view-scrolling)

It may help you if I have understand correct what you want!

Answer (score 0):

You could try calling setEnabled() on the gallery view : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setEnabled(boolean).

When you don't want it moveable set it to disabled, when the network connection finishes you can re-enable it.

Comment: Hi sgarman. Thanks for replying. Your solution, however, didn't work. What is was supposed to do? It behaves exactly the same way as before. I did something like this:

gallery.setEnable(false);
//My Internet connection
onSuccess(){
gallery.setEnable(true);
}

where onSuccess is the callback method that is called when the request returns.